# OData query to filter a collection based on a navigation property's expanded value

Tags: dynamics-crm, odata

I have a `quotes` collection I'd like to filter through a navigation property value.  This navigation property is not a collection, but rather the id to another discrete linked entity.

My use case is `{{ crmApiBaseUrl }}/quotes?$expand=fs_NAVIntegrationMarkerId&$filter=fs_NAVIntegrationMarkerId/fs_name eq 'Open'`

I want to see all of the quotes where the associated fs_NAVIntegrationMarkerId's `fs_name` property value is equal to 'Open'.

The above query returns "The Property (0) is not a primary key of the related entity".

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
{{ crmApiBaseUrl }}/quotes?$expand=fs_NAVIntegrationMarkerId($filter=fs_name eq 'Open')
```

Checkout the `Nested filter in expand` from this documentation https://www.odata.org/getting-started/basic-tutorial/#filter

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the Microsoft Docs reference for [options to apply to expanded tables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/developer/data-platform/webapi/retrieve-entity-using-web-api#options-to-apply-to-expanded-tables). It has great examples of how to apply a filter to an expanded table that are specific to the Dynamics Web API.

```
{{crmApiBaseUrl}}/quotes?$expand=fs_NAVIntegrationMarkerId($filter=fs_name eq 'Open')
```